# If $\{a_1,a_2,..........a_s,a_{s+1},........a_n\}$ is basis for $ V $ such that $\{a_1,........a_s\}$ is basis for $ KerA$. Now my question is that

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to a vector
space $W$ and $\dim V = n$. If $\{a_1,a_2,..........a_s,a_{s+1},........a_n\}$ is basis for $ V $ such that $\{a_1,........a_s\}$ is  basis  for $ KerA$.
Now  my question  is that

$1)$   Is  $\ker A + Im A$  necsessarily a  direct  sum when $V =  W $?

$2)$ If $\{\beta_{1},..... ... ,\beta_{n}\}$
is a   basis for $V$, does it necessarily follow that some $\beta_{i}'s$ fall in $\ker A$?

My  attempts  : for option $1)$  i thinks  it  will  True  because $dim(kerA) + dim(ImA) =n$

i don't  know   about  option $ 2$

Any hints /solution  will be aprreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) No. Take map $T$ such that $Ta_i = 0$ if $i \le s$ and $Ta_i = a_{i - s}$ otherwise, Then $\ker T \cap \mathrm{Im} \; T \neq \{0\}$ as it will include $a_1$. Hence, the sets don't form a direct sum for $V$.

b) No. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with standard basis $\left\{\binom{1}{0},\binom{0}{1}\right\}$ and the linear map $f(a,b) = a - b.$

Comment: I'm not getting. How it's include$a_1$?? Can u elaborate more ??

Comment: Assume $1 \le s < n$. Then $a_1 \in \ker T_1$ as $Ta_1 = 0$. On the other hand, $T {a_{s+1}} = a_1$., so $a_1 \in \mathrm{Im} \; T$

Answer (score 2):

a) Take $d$ as derivation on $E=Vect\big(\{x\mapsto 1, x\mapsto x\}\big)$ which is a linear map.
$Ker\,d =\mathbb{R}.\tilde{1}=Im\,d$ so the kernel and the image of $d$ aren't in direct sum.

b) You can pick also an other basis for $E$, like $\{x\mapsto x, x\mapsto x+1\}$. It is indeed a basis of $E$ but none of the 2 vector has derivative zero.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: im not getting  for   a)   how Kerd = im d  = R.1 ????

Comment: for  b )  why  u take  derivative.....  ?? can u  elaborate  more

Comment: Every vector of $E$ must be of the form: $f:x\mapsto ax+b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. So when you're looking for the kernel of $d$:
$d(f)=0$ iff $a=0$ iff $f(x)=b\in \mathbb{R}.\tilde{1}$

Comment: And when you're trying to calculate $Im\,d$: Let $f\in Im\,d$, then it exists $g\in E$ so of the form $g(x)=ax+b$ which verifies $d(g)=f=a\in\mathbb{R}.\tilde{1}$ so:
$Ker\,d=Im\,d$

Comment: Derivation is a linear map from $E$ to $E$ so it satisfies your condition.